# CakePHP remove "?url=" from the URL after a redirect

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, url-rewriting

I'm using CakePHP for my PHP application.

By default it puts this into a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

After this rule, i am doing this:

```
RedirectMatch ^/resources(.*)$ http://domain.com/community$1 [QSA,R=permanent,L]
```

This makes the redirected URL:

```
http://domain.com/community/view/171/?url=resources/view/171/
```

How can i get rid of the appended "?URL=" without breaking cakephp's routing?

Comment: Have you considered using [CakePHP routes](http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration#Defining-Routes-948) instead?

Comment: They weren't doing what i wanted to, in terms of this, so i used .htaccess. But if you have a routes suggestion, i'm all ears.

Comment: 1) `RedirectMatch ^/resources(.*)$ ...` that is wrong. It should be `RewriteRule` instead of `RedirectMatch` 2) You should have had this rule ABOVE your `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]` line

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to have requests for `/community/*` routed to `ResourcesController`. You should be able to acheive this by adding the following to your `app/config/routes.php`.

```
/**
 * Rename /resources/* to /community/*
 */
Router::connect('/community', array('controller' => 'resources'));
Router::connect('/community/:action/*', array('controller' => 'resources'));
```

The second rule does most of the magic, mapping matching requests to the `ResourcesController` and passing in the action also.

With the above approach you can also take advantage of reverse-routing:

```
echo $this->Html->link('View community', array(
    'controller' => 'resources',
    'action' => 'view',
    $id
));
// outputs a link to `/community/view/171`
```

The first rule is simply there to keep the action name out of the root URL (ie. so `HtmlHelper` links that are reverse-routed become `/community` instead of `/community/index`).

---

Following up on LazyOne's comment, if you are also looking to redirect old `/resources*`-style links for SEO purposes, the following should do the trick:

```
# app/webroot/.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/resources(.*)$ /community$1 [R=301,L] # permanent redirect
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```